# Manipulating timestamp so that the new timestamp is still valid

Tags: python, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe in which each cell of a column contains a timestamp, saved as a string:

```
>>>dataset['DateTime'][1]
'2018-03-14 00:34:46'
```

I would like to create a new column in which those dates are manipulated in the following way:

year += 1,

month += 2,

day += 3,

hour += 4,

minute += 5,

second += 6

(Important to this manipulation is that the initial date and the new date have a one-to-one relation, so that I can transform the date back later onwards)

In my case, the output I am looking for is as follows:

```
>>> dataset['newTimestamp'][1]
'2019-05-17 04:39:52'
```

To do so I am using the `datetime` library to create datetime objects (as a test, I have started with one variable first):

```
timestamp = dataset['DateTime'][1]
p = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Currently I am doing arithmetics on the single variables:

```
year = p.year + 1

if p.month < 12:
    month = p.month + 1
else:
    month = 1
    year += 1
```

However, as with the months, there are exceptions when you can and when you cannnot add values so that the new timestamp is still a real timestamp (12 + 1 = 13, which is not an actual month).

I could program every rule explicitly, but that seems too much work and I expect there are better ways. How could I do this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html).
Also, have a look at [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) module for this kind of manipulations:

```
dataset['newTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['DateTime']) + pd.DateOffset(years=1, months=2, days=3, hours=4, minutes=5, seconds=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try out [beautiful-date](https://github.com/beautiful-everything/beautiful-date) library:

```
pip install beautiful-date
```

And use it like so:

```
from beautiful_date import *

...

dataset['DateTime'].apply(lambda d: d + 1 * years + 2 * months + ... + 6 * seconds)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

strptime() and strftime() are the functions you are looking for.
Just go ahead and google the two fuctions. surely enough,you will be abe to solve the stated problem.
these can be used to directly manipulate date-time quantities

Comment: I have found a way to strip the year, month, day, hour, minute and second from my string. However, what I am looking for is a method to manipulate my current date so that the new date is still an actual data and has a one-to-one correspondance with the old date

Comment: just check the functions. they give you power to add 5 hours to the current timestamp or things like that. the combination of the two function can handle all time related queries.